# get custom attribute value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have two span's and where i have a custom attribute. I want to get the value of it by clicking `<a>`.Here is my html

```
<span data="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $answer['vote']; ?></span>
<a href="#" class="tup" rel="<?php echo $answer['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up design-thumbs" id="thumbs-up-ico"></span></a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {                       
$( ".tup" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var key = $('span').attr('data');
    alert(key);
});
```

Here i get undefined in alert.Where is my error?Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likley getting undefined because you are not selecting the wanted span, use .prev() to select it

```
$( ".tup" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var key = $(this).prev().attr('data');
    //               ^^^^^^^^
    alert(key);
});
```

Comment: @andDev since this is the correct answer, then click the grey tick to make it green :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `data-key`(or another value, data-id, data-attr....) and retrieve it in jQuery with `.data(key)`
You need to get the previous element with `prev()`
try this:
HTML

```
<span data-key="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $answer['vote']; ?></span>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {                       
$( ".tup" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var key = $('span').prev().data('key');
    alert(key);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in this way is not valid.
You can use html5 data-* propery for custom attribute, for example:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<span data-key="some data">value</span>
<script>
var key = $("span").data("key");
</script>
```