# how to use a custom attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have to use a span custom attribute for multiple reasons. Here i can use the attribute first time when clicking a `<a>`. But second time it is undefined in alert. Here is html

```
<span data="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $answer['vote']; ?></span>
<a href="#" class="tup" rel="<?php echo $answer['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up design-thumbs" id="thumbs-up-ico"></span></a>
<a href="#" class="tdown" rel="<?php echo $answer['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" id="thumbs-down-icon"></span></a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {                       
$( ".tup" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = this.rel;
    var key = $(this).prev().attr('data');
    alert(key) ////////it's ok
});

$( ".tdown" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = this.rel;
    var key = $(this).prev().attr('data');
    alert(key);///////Undefined
});
```

});

how can i solve the problem?thanks

**EDIT**
i gave id to it. But my id is given with an array in php. So i had to use another attribute to identify the id

```
<span id="<?php echo $key; ?>" data-key="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $answer['vote']; ?></span>
```

Comment: I don't see any `.tdown` in you html

Comment: data atrribute should be data-* attribute, e.g `data-key="<?php echo $key; ?>"` then use instead: `$(this).prev().data('key');`

Comment: Show the entire markup please.

Comment: now edited.added another <a>

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri already given you example at your qusetion [get custom attribute value in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574992/get-custom-attribute-value-in-jquery). On __how to use a custom attribute in jquery__

Comment: So for `tdown` element, using `var key = $(this).prev().attr('data');` is just wrong. Its not hard to figure out what is wrong, you should read the DOC a minimum...

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri i tried your code.it shows undefined

Comment: `$(".tdown").prev()` is the first link, not the span with the custom attribute.  Give the span an ID and select it with that, instead of `.prev()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work only if link is next to either `<span class="tup">` or `<span class="tdown">`. In any other case it won't work.

You're most likely want to use the following selector to find your span:

```
$(this).prevAll('span[data]').last().attr('data');
```